# RegEx within quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a string of something like

```
$uninstallString = '"C:\Autodesk\Dynamo\Core\Uninstall\unins000.exe" /SILENT'
```

I am trying to use a RegEx to capture the contents of the quotes as well as the remainder after the the space. This is close...

```
$regularExpression = '\"(?<executable>([^\"])\")\s{1,}(?<arguments>(.+))'
```

but I get the closing quote in the executable capture. My understanding is that `[^\"]` is going to capture anything that isn't a quote, allowing the escaped quote that is outside the named capture to work. But of course my understanding is wrong in this case. ;)
I will never need nested quotes, or single quotes, or apostrophe's, so I am trying to keep it as simple as possible and still capture what I need.

Comment: You have `([^\"]+)`, right? I think you want `$regularExpression = '"(?<executable>[^"]+)"\s+(?<arguments>.+)'`

Comment: Damn! No, I missed the +, and I had the closing inside the named capture. It may be time to take a break, I have been staring at this for an hour prior to posting. Ugh.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape characters within the square brackets block (except when you need to match the quotes that wrap your expression) - it already understands characters literally (even dots, ie `[^.]` will match anything that is not a dot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `executable` group captures the trailing `"`, move the `)` to the left:

```
$regularExpression = '"(?<executable>[^"]+)"\s+(?<arguments>.+)'
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28%3F%3Cexecutable%3E%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Carguments%3E.%2B%29&i=%22C%3A%5CAutodesk%5CDynamo%5CCore%5CUninstall%5Cunins000.exe%22%20%2FSILENT). Results:

[image]

Note I removed numbered capturing groups since they seem redundant for your scenario.

**Details**

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?<executable>[^"]+)` - Group "executable": 1+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (note `{1,}` is equal to `+`)
- `(?<arguments>.+)` - Group "arguments": any 1+ chars other than newline.